# How to avoid Switch Case & sscanf Function

Tags: c++

I am working on C++. I am writing code for date format. Using with, we can get default date format from anyother date format. So I have found 240 date formats for this task. So M want to use switch case and sscanf function. Every case have sscanf function to separate day,month, year. So I need 240 cases and 240 sscanf function. Is there any method to avoid lot of swtich and sscanf? If you have any ideas, please let me know guys.

```
case 0:
    sscanf(tsdate.c_str(),"%2d/%2d/%4d",&day,&month,&year);
    break;
case 1:
    sscanf(tsdate.c_str(),"%2d-%2d-%4d",&month,&day,&year);
    break;
case 2:
    sscanf(tsdate.c_str(),"%2d %2d %4d",&day,&month,&year);
    break;
case 3:
    sscanf(tsdate.c_str(),"%2d/%2d/%2d",&day,&month,&year);
    coryear(year);
    break;
case 4:
    sscanf(tsdate.c_str(),"%2d/%2d/%2d",&year,&month,&day); 
    coryear(year);
    break;
```

Like above, I want to put 240 cases and 240 sscanf. Please let me know how to avoid a lot of cases.

Comment: Why is it a problem to have 240 cases? It's tedious to create, but once created it should require very little maintenance and will always be very fast.

Comment: Are the separators the same between the y-m, m-d?

Comment: Aren’t you allowed to use regular expressions? If you used them, you could focus on the order of numbers and wouldn’t have to take care of separators.

Comment: Can you not scan the separators too (use a scan set such as `%[- /]`) so that you can cut down the number of cases.  Failing that, you should be using an array of a structure type to describe how to handle each of your 240 cases (though I confess I'm not sure how you get to 240 options). Writing out 240 `sscanf()` statements is…shall we say 'suboptimal'? Also, do you realize that the `%2d` conversion specification will allow spaces and leading zeros; it only means that if the string starts `"123…"`, the converted value will be `12`, not `123`. Your case 0 would match `" 26/ 12/ 23456"`.

Comment: Also, if you're working on POSIX systems, you should look at the `n$` part of the specification of [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).

Answer (score 3):

you can't avoid the switch cases but you can create multiple function to avoid sscanf:

```
void scanDayFirst(string format)
{
        sscanf(tsdate.c_str(),format,&day,&month,&year);
        break;
}
void scanMonthFirst(string format)
{
        sscanf(tsdate.c_str(),format,&month,&day,&year);
        break;
}
```

and so on.....

the result will be like this:

```
    case 0:
        scanDayFirst("%2d/%2d/%4d");
    case 1:
       scanDayFirst("%2d-%2d-%4d");
    case 2:
        scanDayFirst("%2d %2d %4d");
    case 3:
        scanDayFirst("%2d.%2d.%4d");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
enum { ITEM_YEAR, ITEM_MONTH, ITEM_DAY, NUM_ITEMS };
struct date_format { char const *fmt; int items[NUM_ITEMS]; };

struct date_format const formats[] = 
    { { "%2d/%2d/%4d", { ITEM_DAY, ITEM_MONTH, ITEM_YEAR } }
    , { "%2d-%2d-%4d", { ITEM_MONTH, ITEM_DAY, ITEM_YEAR } }
    /* etc. */
    };

int parts[NUM_ITEMS];   /* Instead of year,month,day */
sscanf(tsdate.c_str(), formats[x].fmt, 
    &parts[formats[x].items[0]],
    &parts[formats[x].items[1]],
    &parts[formats[x].items[2]]);
```

You can extend this to have ITEM_NONE if you want to skip an item, or add extra items, and so on.

NB. If this is C++ then consider using stream input instead of sscanf.

Comment: The OP called `coryear(year)` in the cases where year was encoded as 2 digits... this could be easily added to your table-driven solution, which I like.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enumerating all cases consider instead using a custom language for the format specification:

```
Date x = parseDate(user_input, "dd-mm-yyyy");
```

it will make the function shorter, easier to document and easier to use also improving the readability of the code that uses it. The idea is using codes like

```
yyyy ............. 4-digits year
yy ............... 2-digits year with automatic century computation
mm ............... 2-digits month
m ................ 1 or 2 digits month
dd ............... 2-digits day
d ................ 1 or 2 digits day
anything else .... mandatory character
```

A simple implementation could be

```
Date parseDate(const std::string& input, const std::string& format) {
    const char *src = input.c_str();
    const char *fmt = format.c_str();
    int year=-1, month=-1, day=-1;
    while (*fmt) {
        if (!*src) throw invalid_date(input, format);
        if (strncmp(fmt, "yyyy", 4) == 0) {
            fmt += 4;
            year = getInt(src, 4);
        } else if (strncmp(fmt, "yy", 2) == 0) {
            fmt += 2;
            year = guess_century(getInt(src, 2));
        } else if (strncmp(fmt, "mm", 2) == 0) {
            fmt += 2;
            month = getInt(src, 2);
        } else if (fmt[0] == 'm') {
            fmt += 1;
            month = getInt(src, -1);
        } else if (strncmp(fmt, "dd", 2) == 0) {
            fmt += 2;
            day = getInt(src, 2);
        } else if (fmt[0] == 'd') {
            fmt += 1;
            day = getInt(src, -1);
        } else {
            if (src[0] != fmt[0]) throw invalid_date(input, format);
            src++; fmt++;
        }
   }
   if (*src || year == -1 || month == -1 || day == -1)
     throw invalid_date(input, format);
   return Date(year, month, day);
}
```

NOTE: untested